# Displaying a non-static string on an Android app?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, mobile

I'm making a calculator-type application and it will have a resulting string that is generated by user-given inputs.  This is my first android app, so I am not too familiar with the SDK.  In main.xml I can make the static, non-changing strings, but how can I similarly display a string that can change and has no set value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just do it in your Java code. As you don't provide any snippet of your code, let's suppose you want to give text to the `EditText` that holds the calculations. In that case you will have to do this:

```
editText.setText(stringOfCalculation);
```

In this case, `stringOfCalculation` is an `String` that you have carefully formated by using the calculator buttons.